# Script runner on "naked" Windows system

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2, packaging

I want to write a little executable programm, which runs a cmd-script/batch script and writes the findings in a log files. 
I succeeded doing so in Java, but then I found out that I may not install Java, nor .net, nor anything else. I just have a "naked", freshly installed Windows system where it has to run.

Any ideas how I could solve that?
Another programming language? Or can I pack my Java in my  Executable package? How is that done?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not log directly from that batch script ? No exe needed here.

Comment: from vista and above you have installed .NET by default and the following languages - C#,VisualBasic and jscript.net.  From NT and above you have installed JScript and VBscript. And from 7 and above you have installed powershell by default.  What windows versions you are aiming at? you have a plenty of languages to choose.

Answer (score 0):

C, C++, or Golang.

They don't require installation of heavy runtime systems.

.NET 2.0 should also work if you are only targeting `Windows Server 2008 R2` (.NET 2.0 runtime should be available by default)